# swift infinite scroll up collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Almost everyone can find examples with infinite collectionView load more data when collectionView scrolls to bottom, but maybe anybody known how infinite scroll collectionView from bottom to top?

Like a chat history load more when user scrolls up.

For example.

I have a list with 100000 items and with one of conditions. The app should show to a user items from 9500 to 9600 and when user scrolls up, the app should add to the collectionView items from 9400 to 9500 at the begin of collectionView, and when user scrolls down - the app should add to the collectionView to the end of collectionView and etc.

I've googled and have tried reverse logic for bottom infinite collectionView, but it unsuccessful.
CollectionView just scrolled up to the first item on the list.

Any ideas or tips?

Comment: can you please update your question with code??

Comment: @BhaveshM.Sarsawa what code do you want to see? infinite load to bottom?

Comment: https://github.com/canopas/MarqueeScroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you are describing is expected. Since you scrolled to top the content offset is at zero. And when you added new items the old ones were pushed to the bottom. It will not happen the other way around; when you scroll to bottom and add items beneath them the scroll position stays the same.

To be honest it is all about perspective. The position actually stays the same in both cases (or none) but depends on how you look at it. When you append items at bottom the position should stay the same looking from top (which is a default scenario). But when you add items at top the position stays the same from bottom.

So the solution in your case is that when you add items at the bottom you should change scroll from top:

```
let distanceFromTop = scrollView.contentOffset.y - 0.0;
// Reload data here
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 0.0 + distanceFromTop)
```

which basically means "do nothing at all".

But when you are appending items at the top you need to compute it from bottom:

```
let distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
// Reload data here
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - distanceFromBottom)
```

You should note that you can do this sideways as well. Appending items on the right side would again be transparent. But adding them on the left should be like:

```
let distanceFromRight = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.contentOffset.x;
// Reload data here
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentSize.width - distanceFromRight, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y)
```

I am using `scrollView` as this happens the same to every subclass of it. The same logic can be applied to table view or collection view.

Another note here is that estimated row heights or similar functionalities may cause anomalies when not done correctly. In such cases you may need to compute the offset a bit more smartly.